# How to save 'n' arrays to 'n' npy files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, one-hot-encoding

I have strings like these ones in a file:

```
tactccctccatcccataatataagacatggtcaaacttggcacggtcttcaaaactaatctttaacttttaatttctca
gttggtatcagaggagtggtcctcggaggtttccgcgacggcgccgtccaccaaaccttccgtgcagacgcgtctgctgc
tgttatggtgggtaaaacatatgaaaggcggcccaagcagcccataggccaggccacgccatgagatcaagattaaaggg
tgttcaggccagcaatggacagtttccgggcactgtgccggctccgcgcgcctcggtcccggctcgcgctcgcgcgctcg
cgttatcagcacgagctgcctaagctaatagatactaaaaaaaaatttctgataaaaaaccatatttattatcgactcat
aaagtggtatcagagcttgaagatcctaaagatggcgagtaacaatgttcccttccaagtcccggtgctcacaaagagca
tggtatcagacagccgatcacaagcttccgctccctaacccatcgccgacgacctcaccggccaccacatcctcttctcc
gctggaatagctcagttggttagagcgtgtggctgttaaccacaaggtcggaggttcaagccctccttctagcgcttttt
gagcactgctcccgtccagcaaacggtaccccaggtaccggtaccccggtacgaaacttaatctgaccattgaattagag
gtgttaacccagatcaaatgcctcgttccctgggccgcctcattgtgaggggaagtattgcgacaagtcactaactcttc
cttgagcagagagttgctcattggaatactacaatattcatatattttactggagcttctaaacggattccttcaccatg
aagtgtgatgattggaggtgtgcgggttcgagcgctgtacaactacaccggagaggagcctgatgagctctccttcaaat
gtccactgacctgtaatagagaactggattgctcatgagaccccgatcgttcacttgtaatacattgatagttttcttta
atcaacgggagatgtccaagaccgaataactaagcgaattagtttggacttatcagcgaaatttcagtgatgctgaaagc
aaaatcagtttatcaacgggagatgtccaagaccgaataactaagcgaattagtttggacttatcagcgaaatttcagtg
ctactatgtttaaaaatatgttgaacaaaaaattctctctgttaaaaaaaacagttgggaaatatttttcgaacaattaa
gtaatagccagtcgcacctctactgtactcgaaatacatgtcagtgagattaacattcattattctgaccagacggctta
ttggccatcaaatgagggaaacaggccagctcctcgacaaaaaaagtggcatgagatttatcaaaggattgagaaatgcc
```

I need to [one-hot encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) each line and save to a numpy binary file. I wrote this function for the task.

```
def ohe(padded_file):
    integer_encoder = LabelEncoder()  
    one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto')   
    input_features = []
    with open(padded_file, 'r') as padded:
        padded = padded.readlines()
        arr_nums = [i for i in range(len(padded))]
        for linha in padded:
            linha = linha.strip()
            integer_encoded = integer_encoder.fit_transform(list(linha))
            integer_encoded = np.array(integer_encoded).reshape(-1, 1)
            one_hot_encoded = one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoded)
            stacked = np.stack(one_hot_encoded.toarray())
            input_features.append(stacked)
        np.savez_compressed("seq_arrays.npz", *input_features)
```

It works, but if I need to handle a bigger file containing many thousands of lines and longer strings, depending on the RAM capacity of the computer it can't do the job. So, for the latter case, I thougth I could write a numpy binary file for each line and then join in a same compressed file or even let them in a directory to be used when necessary. WRT that I did the following:

```
def ohe(padded_file):
    integer_encoder = LabelEncoder()  
    one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto')   
    with open(padded_file, 'r') as padded:
        padded = padded.readlines()
        arr_nums = [i for i in range(len(padded))]
        for linha in padded:
            linha = linha.strip()
            integer_encoded = integer_encoder.fit_transform(list(linha))
            integer_encoded = np.array(integer_encoded).reshape(-1, 1)
            one_hot_encoded = one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoded)
            stacked = np.stack(one_hot_encoded.toarray())
            for num in arr_nums:
                save(f'arr_{num}.npy',stacked)
```

It creates a number of files based on the number of lines, but all of them store the same data, which is the last string one-hot encoded. I need to have the first file with the first line one-hot encoded, the second file with the second line one-hot encoded and so on.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `with open(padded, 'r')` `padded` is unknown

Comment: Ah, it is only here. In my code it is all ```padded_file```. I forgot to correct the code I pasted here. Thanks, anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a construct that does not read the whole file but line by line

```
    with open(padded_file, 'r') as padded:
        for i,linha in enumerated(padded):
            linha = linha.strip()
            # ....other stuff
            save(f'arr_{i}.npy',stacked)
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! Btw, there is a typo in your suggestion: ```enumeratyed```.

Comment: @TiagoMinuzzi Sometimes my fingers get entangled